# Excel Formula for auto date/time subtraction

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I want to do the following in cell K14: If cell D14 contains `C17`, take cell F14 and subtract 3 hours and 45 minutes.

The date/time format I am using is a Julian Date/military time, so `16271/1845` minus the 3 hrs 45 minutes would be `16271/1500`.  These date/time values are stored as a text string.  The Julian date is the two digit year followed by the three digit day of the year.

Comment: 1) What happens if D14 contains something else?  2) is C17 a literal text value or a cell reference?  3) Are the date/time values stored in that format, or stored as Excel date/time values and formatted to display like that?

Comment: Well D14 could contain 3 things
1. C17
2. KC135
3. B7
It will be literal text values. And the format is not stored anywhere, is there a way for me to make my own format within excel? If not I could change the format to make it easier

Comment: Just found a way to make my own format, however the Julian date is not a code in excel so that is an issue.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to just keep the first half of the numbers (e.x. 6271) and just subtract the military time format from the second half?

Comment: 1) You describe what you want if it's true that D14="C17".  To use an IF statement, you also need to define what you want if the condition is false.  2) Is the Julian date/time stored as a text string or as an Excel date/time which you format as shown (the solutions will be entirely different)?

Comment: Stored as a text string, excel does not have the date/time format I use. I tried to make my own format in excel, but there are no code for the type I use for the Julian date. I could possibly get the year using yy and then it would read 16271 and that wouldn't be an issue, but the "271" part of that, there is no code for. Julian date is weird, January 1st would be 1. January 31st would be 31. February 1st will be 32 Julian date.

Comment: So, I got the right side of the formula I guess I need. I just used in cell K14 : =F14 - Time(1,45,0) but im not very good with this stuff. haha. Also, I can get rid of the "6" on the date part that I use, so if we could just figure out how to properly get the correct Julian date as a format this would work! I only really need the Julian date, the "271" part. So 271/1845

Comment: So I have a formula that could help. If I had the full date in, say, cell F20 =TEXT(F20,"")&TEXT((F20-DATEVALUE("1/1/"&TEXT(F20,"yy"))+1),"000") that would produce a proper Julian date...

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-day-of-year.  Working with military time, you will either need to get Excel to recognize the string as a time, or parse the values into hours and minutes rather than powers of 10.  And if you have times earlier than 3:45AM, your subtraction will need to adjust the day value.

Comment: So how do I combine the formulas to get the Julian date, recognizing what is in cell D14, and subtracting 3:45 from it?

Comment: If you have a time before 3:45AM on January 1, the year will also be affected.  You've managed to pick the worst case format for both date and time in terms of complicating the solution.  You might want to just convert what you have to Excel date/time, do the math, and then build the displayed value if you want it redisplayed like that.

Comment: @fixer1234 , Alright! Thanks for all your help! I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: @fixer1234 , Only one more question... I have it auto doing the time portion in my spreadsheet, is there a way I can have the formula only grab a certain time portion of a cell? say in A1 I have 272/1845 can I put in A2 a formula that grabs that 1845 and subtract from there? And also just drag the "272/" over and not do anything with and put it in front of the answer to the formula? I have everything else figured out besides that :(

Comment: Sure, unless you have an entry earlier than 3:45AM, in which case you also need to do math on the day.  And if that day is January 1, you would also have to do math on the year.  You can use LEFT and RIGHT to split the date-time pieces, and & to concatenate the pieces for a new displayed value.

Comment: There's the potential to get into trouble on the date/time math using your starting point, so I posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for you based on the problem as originally defined:

[image: screenshot]

Cell A1 contains a sample date/time in your format.

B1 translates that to an Excel date/time with this formula:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,2),1,1)+MID(A1,3,3)-1+MID($A1,7,2)/24+RIGHT($A1,2)/1440
```

This uses text functions to parse the pieces and builds the date from the year, using January 1, then adds the day count (and subtracts 1 since the year can't start on January 0).  Since Excel stores times as fraction of a day, the hour value is divided by 24 and the minute value is divided by 1440 minutes in a day.

Now your entry is in a form on which Excel can do date/time math.  This is the cleanest approach since you could potentially run into values where you would otherwise need to adjust the day count or year, and doing power-of-ten math on times gets messy.

C1 contains the date/time after subtracting 3 hours 45 minutes:

```
=B1-TIME(3,45,0)
```

D1 translates the result back to your format:

```
=TEXT(C1,"yy")&TEXT(INT(C1)-DATE(YEAR(C1),1,0),"00#")&"/"&TEXT(MOD(C1,1),"hhmm")
```

It concatenates the pieces using `&` to build the string.

- Three digit day is the date of the result minus "January 0" of the year of the result at the same time of day (the time is part of the stored value and rounding could affect the day count).  The INT function extracts the date of the result at midnight to match the time of the calculated January 0 date.
- The MOD function provides the fractional part of the result, which is the time portion, and uses the TEXT function to build the hours and minutes display in 24 hour format.

You could do this all in one, difficult to maintain, cell by substituting formulas for cell references.  In D1, replace each C1 reference with the formula in C1 after the initial `=`.  Then replace each B1 reference with the formula in B1 after the initial `=`.

Your question describes an IF condition, but you don't provide enough information for it.  Substitute F14 instead of A1 in your formula to refer to the correct entry cell.  The IF in cell K14 would look like this:

```
=IF(D14="C17",formula based on above answer,"")
```

Don't duplicate the initial `=` from my answer formula when you insert the formula from the answer into the IF.  I assumed a null (the empty quotes, which will give you a blank cell), for the false condition, but you can make that anything you want.

Comment: @creidhne, great catch! Thanks. I corrected the formula and incorporated some of your simpler code.